# пустой архив репозитория на локальном Gitlab-е

Tags: gitlab

Я, как начинающий пользователь, пока мало знаю в чем может быть проблема. Есть установленный локальный сервер Gitlab, на нем храниться уже несколько созданных проектов. На главной странице проекта есть кнопка "скачать архивом". Когда скачиваю его, то он пустой, может не хватает каких-то установленных компонентов на сервере? можно ли это узнать в настройках аккаунта (аккаунт администратора)?

Comment: а у вас есть доступ к логам сервера?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman эти логи? [скрин](http://prntscr.com/eecmm5)

Comment: да. посмотрите в них, что происходит когда вы запрашиваете архив.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman ничего в лог недобавилось, меня смущает что все коммиты со статусами " build: pending", переходя по ссылке коммита - не хватает .gitlab-ci.yml который  будет выполняться в компонентом Gitlab CI, может и за этого пустые архивы?

Comment: компонент Gitlab CI неустановлен